# React-Native Issue while running "npx react-native run-android"

Tags: react-native

while running npx react-native run-android it shows an error

[image: click to see the error]

Comment: Please post error text as text and not as an image. That way the search & google will find it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because you are connected with any Android device or any emulator, to connect with your emulator, you need to add a virtual device, to add a virtual device please follow these links https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds and https://developers.foxitsoftware.com/kb/article/create-an-emulator-for-testing-in-android-studio/

then run adb devices in your root-project in terminal, you must be able to run the app..